# Using the imdb gem to show and its poster function in an erb file with sinatra and ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, imdb

I am trying to access posters(from imdb gem) in a Ruby server using sinatra and then display them in my view (erb file). It show an error(undefined method for poster) but shows no error if I apply the code with `.movies` as below. Below is the calling of imdb gem and my code from the erb. Hope someone can help me as I am new to using gems. Thanks.

```
# This is the file from my server.rb file in sinatra 
# The :search_term takes an input from a HTML form.
post "/calculate" do
  movie = params[:search_term]
  search1 = Imdb::Search.new(movie)
  @output = search1 
  @output.movies
  redirect "/movie_result"
end

#erb file content
'<%= @output %>'
```

Comment: Can you post the `erb` file name? It can be helpful in debugging this

Comment: All I have in the erb file is show here, not sure if its correct. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

It is not about gems. It's about request, response cycle. Let me show you your mistake.

When client sends some params to you with post method, your code makes a processing and then responses with redirect. *Not with any local parameters to manipulate and show inside a view file.*

Rendering a view file with local params is different from redirecting an action to a new route.

consider example.

**routes.rb**

```
get '/mocko' do
  @x = "Mocko"
  redirect '/locko'
end

get '/locko' do
  erb :locko, :layout => false
end
```

**locko.erb**

```
Is there x?<strong><%= @x.nil? ? "No" : "Yes" %></strong>
```

Output (When I request for `mocko` it redirects me `locko` immediately)

[image]

P.S. Let me know if you'll able to solve from there on.

Comment: Thanks for the response I got it working as I removed the redirect at the bottom of the post calculate and replaced it with erb(:movie_result) which seemed to work and then in my image placement I changed it to 
 <img src="<%= @movie2 %>" alt="Smiley face" height="140" width="142"> which seemed to do the trick. Thanks a lot for the help, much appreciated. :)